# Book where an elf is possessed by a demon

Tags: story-identification, books

The protagonist is an elf who is possessed by a demon. He has to bring this demon to where it can get free. The main character gets into a fight with two elves that have small dragon tattoos that also move. The main character is unkillable and when he calls for the demons power, he gets it. The cost is that the more he uses the power, the more the demon takes over.

At the beginning of the book, the main character kills a Minotaur while riding a giant lizard. At the end, the demon turns on the main character, but is stabbed by some dagger, and disappears, taking part or all of the protagonist's soul.

I've been trying to figure out what this book is for years for years!

Comment: This is a good start, but if you can visit https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info, there's more prompts for information you can add. For example, when did you read this? Was it a paperback? Hardback? Graphic novel? How long was the book? Did it look like part of a series?

Comment: Just a note - you can play as this possessed elf in the DLC for the "Total War Warhammer II" called "The Shadow and the Blade". You can see intro here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sPbjHEnSDE

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for *[Bloodstorm](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1052307.Bloodstorm)* by Mike Lee and Dan Abnett, second book of the *Darkblade series*, set in the *Warhammer Fantasy* universe.

[image: Front cover of The Daemon's Curse]

> Possessed by the foul daemon Tz'arkan, the ruthless dark elf anti-hero Malus Darkblade is forced to seek a number of magic artefacts or his soul will be forfeit. He will have to call on all his cunning and dark wits to survive a magic labyrinth and defeat its fearsome guardian.

There's a decent (if very informal) summary of the books in [this 1d4chan article](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/Malus_Darkblade#Bloodstorm) that seems to cover the plot you remember.

> Malus returned to Hag Graef to plan getting the second artifact - the Idol of Kolkuth, but got captured by Lurhan's soldiers. He was gruesomely tortured by his father, who was trying to manipulate him into requesting death so Eldire couldn't blame Lurhan for Malus' death. A combination of spite and Tz'arkan's power kept Malus alive, long enough for Eldire to visit him in secret. Eldire and Nagaira worked together to free him, magically heal his wounds and inducted him into the Slaaneshi cult. Then Malus learned they didn't want him, but Tz'arkan, so he sought a way out. During this time, Malus took on another retainer, a witty, down-to-earth (for a Dark Elf) city guard named Hauclir. Eventually his schemes came to the attention of the Drachau of Hag Graef, and Malus made him an offer. There was a fleet of Nurgle-worshiping pirates called the Skinriders - named for the fact that they lost their skins due to disease or injury and wore the skin of those they fought or captured - who often attacked the Dark Elves. Malus asked for a Writ of Iron from the Drachau - a legal document that gives the carrier the authority of the issuer, and since this was issued by the ruler of Hag Graef Malus was now the second-most powerful person in the city (with the caveat that if the carrier failed their duty, the Writ would be melted down and the molten remains were poured down their throat) - and in exchange Malus would hunt down and destroy the Skinriders.

....

> They infiltrated the Skinriders base and encountered their chieftain, a Daemon Prince of Nurgle wearing a cloak of flayed skin. Then the Dark Elves were betrayed by Tanithra, who had taken Yasmir captive. She confessed to everyone her part in the plan to defeat the Skinriders and offered to pledge herself to the Skinriders on the condition that she can keep one of the Dark Elf ships and be its captain, while also flaying Yasmir and wearing her skin. Urial attacked to save Yasmir and a battle broke out between Malus, Bruglir's loyal crew and Tanithra and the Skinriders, resulting in the deaths of all in the room but Urial, Yasmir and Malus. Malus broke away during the battle to find the Idol of Kolkuth, which was in an interdimensional maze. Malus was unable to navigate, and asked Tz'arkan for a rope - being Tz'arkan, the daemon unravelled Malus' blood vessels from his body and used them as rope. After fighting past a minotaur, Malus got the Idol - his body restored at the cost of Tz'arkan spreading his influence, and Malus found his way back as the Dark Elves wiped out the Skinriders, but there was no sign of Urial or Yasmir.

Found by searching for `novel elf possessed by demon`